# Braking causes steering wheel vibration

Tags: brakes

I replaced my front brake pads less than a year ago. I now am having a steering wheel vibration when I brake and believe my rotors are warped. I checked my pads and they have a lot of pad left on them. Can I just change my rotors and still use my pads?

Comment: More than likely the rotors weren't bedded correctly when the pads were changed.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't re-use the pads - they will have worn into the shape of the damaged/misaligned discs, and so won't bed properly on new discs.